# EF TPH inheritance lost in Web Api JSON

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, inheritance, asp.net-web-api

I've successfully set up some classes that use [TPH EF inheritance](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph), `MyBaseClass`, `MySubClass1`, `MySubClass2` etc.

When querying using Linq `context.MyBaseClasses.Where(...)`, the objects returned all correctly use the subclass specified by the Discriminator field in the database. (So I might end up with a list containing a mix of objects of `MySubClass1`, or `MySubClass2`.)

However, when I pass these objects to a WPF application, via a JSON Web Api call, the objects received are all of `MyBaseClass`, rather than the correct sub class they started off at.

The object property they are returned via is of type `public virtual List<MyBaseClass> MyThings`, so I guess it makes sense that they all end up as this type, but I want to retain the correct sub class type for each object.

How do I achieve this? Do I need to force the EF Discriminator field to be sent along with all the other data somehow?

**Edit**

**1.**

At the client end, I'm now attempting to deserialize the JSON (including $type data) like so (with no luck, the items are still converted back to their base class)

```
HttpResponseMessage response = GetClient().GetAsync(url).Result;

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string jsonMessage;
    using (Stream responseStream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
    {
        jsonMessage = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
    }


    List<My.Domain.Models.MyBaseClass> thingsToReturn;

    //new method    
    thingsToReturn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<My.Domain.Models.MyBaseClass>>(jsonMessage);

    //previous method
    //thingsToReturn = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<My.Domain.Models.MyBaseClass>>().Result;

    return thingsToReturn;
}
```

**2.**

Following Anish's advice re `SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling`, I've now got $type information appearing in my JSON, however this is of type `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SubClass1_5E07A4CE2F037430DC7BFA00593....` is this OK for the client end to deserialize back into `SubClass1` successfully?

Comment: Are you using Json.Net to serialize the objects on the Asp.Net side and to deserialize on the WPF side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Many, many thanks to Anish**, who's answer set me off on the right track, along with [this excellent article](https://kirmir.wordpress.com/2014/05/16/polymorphic-serialization-using-newton-json-net-in-httpcontent/).

The steps I had to take to get the types of the inherited objects to pass through the web api service are as follows:

**Server Side**

The key things were to set the JsonFormatter Serializer `TypeNameHandling` setting to `TypeNameHandling.Auto`. This can be done in `WebApiConfig.Register()`, but it will then obviously add a $type property to all JSON objects returned by your web service calls, or, you can simply decorate the property of the object you need the $type for.

*WebApiConfig Method*

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Auto;
```

*Property Decoration Method*

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(ItemTypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Auto)]
public virtual List<MyBaseClass> Things { get; set; }
```

To get the correct value in the $type property in the JSON, and not the EF proxy class name, I turned off the `ProxyCreationEnabled` property before performing the Linq query that returned the objects based on MyBaseClass.

```
dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
List<MyBaseClass> things = dbContext.MyBaseClasses.Include("This").Include("That").ToList();
```

**Client Side**

I had to add a `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` with `SerializerSettings = { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto }` to the `ReadAsAsync()` call and then the (correctly typed) objects mapped to their sub class happily.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = GetClient().GetAsync(url).Result;

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    //this formatter responds to the $type parameter passed in the JSON to allow us to correctly map object types
    //https://kirmir.wordpress.com/2014/05/16/polymorphic-serialization-using-newton-json-net-in-httpcontent/
    var formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
    {
        SerializerSettings = { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto }
    };

    List<MyBaseClass> thingsToReturn;
    thingsToReturn = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<MyBaseClass>>(new List<MediaTypeFormatter> { formatter }).Result;
    return productTestsToReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a serialization concern.

You can customize *Json.Net's* serializer settings to include type information with your json objects.

Add this to your `HttpConfiguration`:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
```

Where `config` is the `HttpConfiguration` instance that you use to configure and initialize *Asp.Net WebApi*.

This will tell *Json.Net* to add some type information to each json object that has type ambiguity. Such an object would look like this:

```
{
    "$type":"MyProjectContainingMyTypes.MySubClass1, MyProjectContainingMyTypes",
    "Name": "Tyrion Lannister",
    "DisplayName": "The Imp",
    "Traits": ["funny", "awesome", "clever"]
}
```

*Json.Net* will know how to deal with this when you deserialize this on the *WPF* side.

This should work, in your *WPF* app:

```
var things = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyBaseClass>>(jsonString);
```

Then you can cast the objects in the `things` list to their respective derived types.

Of course, your *WPF* application will need to have a reference to the project where you define `MyBaseClass` and `MySubClass1`.

**Edit**

> Thanks Anish, that's almost sorted it. I can see the correct $type data in the JSON, I'm just being a dunce, and I'm not sure how to get the WebApi response as a jsonString? At the minute I'm doing response.Content.ReadAsAsync>().Result; to auto deserialize the data.

In response to your comment, you can read the content as a string like this:

```
var jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

**Edit 2**

> Anish, thanks so much for your input. As you can see, I've managed to get the JSON as a string now, but even using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject I'm still getting the same issue. Do you think it is (as I mention in Edit 2) to do with the $type being returned from the service incorrectly (as an EF proxy type)?

In response to your comment, yes you will **not** be able to deserialize the EF proxy type into the type you want. This issue needs to be resolved on the *WebApi* side.

The proxy classes are created to allow you to *lazy load* entities. Proxies are generally used represent referenced/nested entities. This allows the fetching of referenced entities from the database to be deferred until required, if required at all.

Here is a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#lazySerialization) to some documentation around *lazy* and *eager* loading entities with *EF*.

**Solution**

You want to *hydrate* the list of objects in your *WebApi* controller action and return it, this will tell *EF* to load the entities from the database and new up instances of your classes.

You have a few options here:

**Option 1**

Call `ToList()` on the query to hydrate the collection:

```
var result = (from t in dbContext.Things select t).ToList();
```

or

```
var result = dbContext.Things.ToList();
```

Naturally, you don't want to return an unbounded result set so add a range:

```
var result = (from t in dbContext.Things select t).Skip(0).Take(10).ToList();
```

or

```
var result = dbContext.Things.Skip(0).Take(10).ToList();
```

Bear in mind that with method you will have to explicitly hydrate nested objects like this:

```
var result = dbContext
             .Things
             .Include(t => t.SomePropertyThatRepresentsSomeNestedObject) 
             .Skip(0)
             .Take(10)
             .ToList();
```

**Option 2**

Turn off *lazy loading* for your DbContext.

Personally, I'd go with *Option 1*, I think it is better to know your entities and have control over when and what you hydrate.

Comment: Thanks Anish, that's almost sorted it. I can see the correct $type data in the JSON, I'm just being a dunce, and I'm not sure how to get the WebApi response as a jsonString? At the minute I'm doing `response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<MyBaseClass>>().Result;` to auto deserialize the data.

Comment: Anish, thanks so much for your input. As you can see, I've managed to get the JSON as a string now, but even using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` I'm still getting the same issue. Do you think it is (as I mention in Edit 2) to do with the $type being returned from the service incorrectly (as an EF proxy type)?

Comment: No problem buddy, I've updated my answer that, hopefully, will help.

Comment: Hi Anish, like I said, many, many thanks for your help. I've added my own answer just to record all the separate steps I had to sort out to get it working, as adding it all into the question would make it even more unreadable! Basically, it was adding the `TypeNameHandling` to the Server AND Client that was the root of the problem.